# How do I add up all the results from a for loop?

Tags: c#, loops, math, for-loop

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int five = 5;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0;   i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (i % five == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This simply prints out all the multiples of 5, that are less than 1000.

Is there any way I can add up all of the results of the for loop?

Comment: What "results" are you referring to? Do you want to sum the values you are writing out to the console?

Comment: You already have a `sum` variable and the right `if` statement in place.....

Comment: You just need to add a `sum = sum + i;` in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

What means "add up"? You can add them to a collection like a `List<int>`:

```
List<int> multpiplesOf5 = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        multpiplesOf5.Add(i);
    }
}
```

If you want to output all you can loop them:

```
foreach(int i in multpiplesOf5)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

or use `String.Join`:

```
string result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, multpiplesOf5);
```

Here is a concise LINQ version of the loop:

```
List<int> multpiplesOf5 = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Where(i => i % 5 == 0).ToList();
```

---

If you instead want to sum them up you can use the LINQ extension [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.95).aspx):

```
int sumOfAll = multpiplesOf5.Sum();
```

If you want the count of numbers which were divisible by 5:

```
int count = multpiplesOf5.Count();
```

or without the list with a single LINQ query:

```
int count = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Count(i => i % 5 == 0);
```

Comment: Doesn't he just want to add them up (i.e. sum them)?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: hmm, good point, could be. So edited my answer accordingly. He needs the collection anyway, so the first part is not useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using System.Linq;

 var sumOfFives = Enumerable
   .Range(0, 1000)
   .Where(i => i % 5 == 0)
   .Sum();
```

Comment: Oops, meant `Where`, thanks @TimeSchmelter will correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get the sum of all the numbers that are multiples 5 then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int five = 5;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0;   i < 1000; i++){

        if (i % five == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```